# Is there any web, scripts, or tools to calculate number of registered OSM user in each country?

Tags: openstreetmap

I will have talk about OSM in next few week and I just wondering if there any tools, scripts, or websites to showing the statistic of number registered OSM User per country.

Because I have an idea to displaying the number of registered user (for example by countries or one country per years) in my talk in order to compare which country that have the biggest number of registered OSM users.

One website that i found is here: https://osmstats.neis-one.org/

But it only showing the whole world, not in specific country. When i moved into the countries tab in that web, it only show the number of active user each day.

Any advice?

Comment: Registered users is not really a relevant number. Not every registered user actually contributes to OSM. The number of active users is far more interesting in my opinion.

Comment: You **can** add your home location to your OSM profile, but don't have to. Mine is empty.

Comment: @scal ah i see your point. Compare to total number of registered users or active users in the world, i show how many active users in several country

Answer (score 1):

If you want to analyse the data yourself, I'd start from here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Changeset#Changeset_Dump .  That may however be more work than you want to just to get some headline numbers for a presentation.

If you don't, then there are more "who did what where" links from http://resultmaps.neis-one.org/ .  Also if you want to monitor changes by time in different areas perhaps look at one of the "whodidit" feeds mentioned at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Quality_assurance#WhoDidIt .

Another thing to consider is that many edits "aren't just in one country", for example http://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/51370515 (modifying 3 items in Australia and Canada).

Comment: Using whodidit i think its not suitable for one large or wide country like thailand and indonesia. I think i'm gonna play around with pascal neis's tools like latest osm contributor, who's around me, or osm stats

Comment: The reason that I mentioned whodidit was to allow you to compare small areas with others both in-country and elsewhere.  In the case of Thailand, contribution patterns around tourist areas (e.g. of ad-hoc users using MAPS.ME) has been discussed over at the [forum](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewforum.php?id=46).  I bet you'll see a very different pattern of contributions there compared to, say, residential, commercial, or indstrial areas.